# change amber/weather alert turns

Tags: customization

does anyone know how to change the alert tone for weather/amber alerts? I'd like to get them, but I can't stand the ear splitting EAS tone, especially in the middle of the night.

Cyanogenmod 10.2 if it helps, I don't mind overwriting system audio files if possible.

Comment: Are these the alerts that are shown via Google Now?

Comment: No, the default SMS app.